# PyQt4: Set size of the tab bar in QTabWidget

Tags: python, qt, height, pyqt4, tabbar

How would you change the height of the tab bar in a QTabWidget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a customized `QTabBar` and overwrite its `tabSizeHint` method. Then set that customised `QTabBar` as the bar of your `QTabWidget` using the `QTabWidget.setTabBar` method.

I think the following (non tested) code could help you:

```
class TabBar(QTabBar):

   def tabSizeHint(self, index):
       width = QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index).width()
       return QSize(width, your_wanted_height)
```

You can find other customization examples [here](http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Customising%20tab%20bars).