# PyQt4: Change text size and font on QTabBar

Tags: python, text, size, pyqt4, tabbar

How would you change the text size and font in a QTabWidget?

```
class TabBar(QtGui.QTabBar):
    def ???(self, ???):
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a stylesheet. You don't need to subclass for that. But from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428917/pyqt4-set-size-of-the-tab-bar-in-qtabwidget), you are doing that already. You might as well put this in the `__init__` too..

```
class TabBar(QtGui.QTabBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TabBar, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setStyleSheet('font-size: 18pt; font-family: Courier;')
```

If you don't want to use a custom `QTabBar` the equivalent would be setting the stylesheet on relevant `QTabWidget` with a selector of `QTabBar`:

```
myTabWidget.setStyleSheet('QTabBar { font-size: 18pt; font-family: Courier; }')
```

Comment: thanks again @Avaris! hmm but the text won't display correctly, there's more margin under the text than on top, is there a solution for this?

Comment: @X.Jacobs: How much more margin? Look fine here. Btw, `text-align` specifies the horizontal alignment.

Comment: [here](https://www.box.com/s/8pj3j3qui6dx2qfj3ggi) is how it's displayed, probably because of the close tab icons, is it possible to resize that as well?

Comment: @X.Jacobs: There is a `QTabBar::close-button` css selector, but you can't customize the size from that since the button itself is actually a widget. You can however put a new button with desired size with `QTabBar.setTabButton`, or resize the old one after getting it with `QTabBar.tabButton`. But I'm afraid you have to do it manually for each tab.

Comment: too much of a customization hah guess i'll go with double click to close and no icons whatsoever :)